# Copy list column value to another in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell

Within a SharePoint Online list I am attempting to update a column based on another column, all within the same list.

List - TestUpdate

Source Column - Created

Destination Column - Scan Date

I have attempted the following but get PowerShell error that Cannot index into a null array. This suggests I am not correctly collecting the site name?

```
$listName = "TestUpdate"

$web = Get-SPOSite -Identity "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"

$list = $web.Lists[$listName]

$items = $list.items

foreach($item in $items)

{
    $user = $item["Created"]

    $item["Scan_x0020_Date"] = $user

    $item.Update()

}
```

I value your opinions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it by using the SharePoint Online PowerShell directly, that is mainly for maintenance tasks.

Luckily we have the [PnP PowerShell Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets) that makes these kinds of operations quite easy:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename" -Credentials (Get-Credential)
$listname = "TestUpdate"
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $listname

foreach ($item in $items) {
  Set-PnPListItem -List $listname -Identity $item.Id -Values @{"Scan_x0020_Date"=$item["Created"]}
}
```

Comment: Outstanding. Saved me a LOT of time @Rune-Sperre Thank you!